# ansible variable in host_vars not read

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ι have the following

hosts

```
[server1]
192.168.1.1
```

and the following file structure

```
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   └── server1
├── playbook.yaml
```

in hosts_vars the variable is defined

```
my_variable: test
```

if I run the playbook

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --limit server1
```

i get following error

```
fatal: [192.168.1.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'my_variable' is undefined"}
```

It seems the host_vars is not read
Someone knows what I am missing?
Many Thanks!!

Comment: You're using the host_vars for the group `server1`. Either rename the folder name to `group_vars` or rename the file to the hostname.

Comment: [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html). Pay attention to the very first chapter => Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups